# How to populate an empty vector in R using a function?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, vector

First of all, I am initializing an empty vector and I want to populate it whenever I call the function. I want the element added to be added to the empty vector and so on but, when I call the function nothing happens so I not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
 empty_vec<-c()

func<-function(num){
  
  for (numbers in num) {   
    i<-sqrt(numbers)
    empty_vec<- c(empty_vec,i)
  }
}

func(4) # When calling the func,4 isn't getting added to the empty_vec.
```

Comment: (1) Reaching out from the inside of your function to *read* an external variable is bad practice, and can lead to at best difficult-to-troubleshoot code. Worse, `<-` will not overwrite the value of the `empty_vec` outside of `func`, it will make a "copy" of the data within the function that masks it, and when the function exits, that updated copy will cease to exist. (2) There are functions for doing that (see `<<-` and `assign`), but they should not be used regularly, and suggest a poor design. I discourage them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize `empty_vec` within `func` and return it (so you should put `empty_vec` at the bottom as well), e.g.,

```
func <- function(num) {
  empty_vec <- c()
  for (numbers in num) {
    i <- sqrt(numbers)
    empty_vec <- c(empty_vec, i)
  }
  empty_vec
}
```

such that

```
> func(c(4, 5, 6, 7))
[1] 2.000000 2.236068 2.449490 2.645751
```

---

Since what you are doing is to calculate `sqrt`, you can do it just via

```
> sqrt(c(4,5,6,7))
[1] 2.000000 2.236068 2.449490 2.645751
```

Comment: More generally, `empty_vec` is unnecessary for many easily-defined operations, even if it's not a built-in function.  For example, `func <- function(num) log(num) * sqrt(num) + 10` (or whatever other arbitrary operations you like) can simply take a vector as input: `func(c(4, 6, 9))`.